# Foreign Data Wrapper - mapping nvarchar datatype

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, nvarchar, foreign-data-wrapper, tds-fdw

I have linked a SQL Server database with a PostgreSQL database via `tds_fdw` extension .

I mapped SQL Server tables into PostgreSQL foreign tables. Connection successfully.

I have got problem on mapping `nvarchar` datatype to Postgres. I mapped `nvarchar` as `varchar`, because SQL Server `varchar` and `nvarchar` is the same for PostgreSQL. But `nvarchar` columns didn't mapped correctly (stored as `?` for some symbols).

How can I correctly map `nvarchar` from SQL Server to an equivalent datatype in Postgresql ?

I created Postgresql database with an UTF8 encoding

Comment: SQL Server does not use UTF-8. These may help explain things a little: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/362867/add-support-for-storing-utf-8-natively-in-sql-server and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/232580/description-of-storing-utf-8-data-in-sql-server